# Meteor multiple fields query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a `Calendar` collection with various calendar documents but some of their attributes have different values:

**doc1**

```
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-04T07:01:40.158Z"),
    "usuarios_admin_ids" : [ 
        "Ys6fiychXcSfCgWox"
    ],
    "title" : "yyyyy",
    "state" : "public",
    "fechaModificacion" : "2016-10-15 08:00:00",
    "master_ids" : [ 
        "null"
    ]
}
```

**doc2**:

```
{
    "_id" : 3.0,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-04T07:01:40.158Z"),
    "usuarios_admin_ids" : [ 
        "Ys6fiychXcSfCgWox"
    ],
    "title" : "xxxxxx",
    "state" : "public",
    "fechaModificacion" : "2016-10-12 08:00:00",
    "master_ids" : [ 
        1
    ]
}
```

I am having problems implementing a query that will fetch me this:

> "document with `Title`=yyyy and document with `masters_id`=1."

This should return the two documents above because the `master_ids` in `doc2` is pointing to the `_id` of `doc1` in a way that if `doc1` doesn't exist I wont get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add to @asdfJackal answer which is correct.

$in is used as "master_ids" is an array.

```
Calendar.find({$or: [{"title": "yyyy"}, {"master_ids": {$in: [1]}}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your query filter:

```
{$or: [{title: "yyyy"},{masters_id: 1}]}
```

Comment: thanks but Monasha anwer was more accurate. The array part was really important.

Comment: No problem, glad you found and answer that works for you.